# Error in {% markdown %} and {% textile %} filters in Django Nonrel

Tags: django, markdown, django-nonrel

I'm having trouble using Markdown in Django Nonrel. I followed this [instructions](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django) (added             `'django.contrib.markup'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, include `{% load markup %}` in the template and use `|markdown` filter after installing python-markdown) but I get the following error:

```
Error in {% markdown %} filter: The Python markdown library isn't installed.
```

In this line:

```
/path/to/project/django/contrib/markup/templatetags/markup.py in markdown
    they will be silently ignored.
    """
    try:
        import markdown
    except ImportError:
        if settings.DEBUG:
            raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("Error in {% markdown %} filter: The Python markdown library isn't installed.") ...
        return force_unicode(value)
    else:
        # markdown.version was first added in 1.6b. The only version of markdown
        # to fully support extensions before 1.6b was the shortlived 1.6a.
        if hasattr(markdown, 'version'):
            extensions = [e for e in arg.split(",") if e]
```

It seems obvious that `import markdown` is causing the problem but when I run:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> import elementtree
>>> import markdown
```

everthing works alright.

Running Markdown 2.0.3, Python 2.7 and latest version of Django Nonrel.

**UPDATE**: I installed textile and it doesn't work. It produces the same error.

**UPDATE 2**: This is an issue related with Django Nonrel. I took an older Django project (1.3.1), and works as expected.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, newbie mistake.

Turns out that Django Nonrel couldn't find markdown because for some reason, it wasn't installed in a python path it was looking for. In this case, markdown was installed in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` instead of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` or some other usual place. So I copied the markdown folder to a place listed by python path, and the error went away.